# Date cell changes value when copied between sheets in the same workbook

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that copies data from the 'Form Responses' sheet to another sheet, triggered on form submission. For some reason though, some of the copied entries have a time stamp that's off by 1-2 seconds. How is this possible?

My script seems simple enough - and it doesn't directly modify the values it is copying either:

```
function newEntries() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("--");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses"));
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var source = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 11);

  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Request Off Sheet");

  var Avals = destSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  var lastRow = Alast;

  source.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, 12), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

Comment: A better way is to use the event object that accompanies the form submit event. You can directly write the incoming row data to the alternate sheet without needing to read it from the original destination sheet.

Comment: OK right, do you know how that's addressed?

Comment: Yes, use the event object: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit . Then, instead of `Range#copyTo` you'll use `Range#setValues` or `Sheet#appendRow`